# "what" as a form of "which"

Tags: word-choice, which-what

Is it standard to use "what" as a form of "which," such as in the sentence:

> The tour guide let us know what items were permitted to be taken along on the trip.

In this instance I prefer "what" because it refers to categories of items as opposed to specific items.

Comment: In this example, *what* is **not** a form of *which**. The two words give different meanings to the sentence. You may need to set aside that presumption and then work on understanding the difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That reference is highly recommended reading for the OP. However, the presumption that *what* is being used here as a "form" of *what* is incorrect.

Comment: @Kris: I don't see ***what*** you mean. OP's context is identical to *"Tell me **what** books I need"*, **which** so far as I'm concerned can only ever mean the same as *"Tell me **which** books I need"*. My own usages here can't be switched, obviously, but the ones in my quoted examples are simply stylistic choices (though overwhelmingly, people tend to choose ***what*** in both mine and OP's examples).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your inference is respected. However, see also my first comment, which incidentally is at variance with the opinion you hold.

Comment: @Kris: I really *don't* see what you mean. You say "the two words give different meanings", but I don't know what different meanings you're thinking of. It seems to me OP's sentence means the same regardless of whether it uses *which* or *what*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question in any case is better asked on ELL.

Comment: @Kris: I can't really see why it's better suited to ELL than to ELU either. I agree with the top answer on the linked question that *which* implies *which of an implicit or explicit set of options*, and I don't specifically disagree with the idea that *which* is "more formal". But it seems like a *very* fine distinction to me in OP's context here, where I can only suppose *which* implies *which of the things we were already intending to take*, but *what* might imply *out of all **feasible** things*. Is that the distinction you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!  I had always thought that one would use "which" if one were listing items from a list, including a phrase which would if expanded become a list, and use "what" for that not in a list, or expandable as such.  My examples:

- The tour guide let us know which items we were permitted to bring on the trip.
- Wisdom dictates which actions to take and which to avoid.

vs

- The tour guide let us know what to expect on the trip.
- The police officer told me what to do.

I may be completely off, it wouldn't be the first time, but it seems right to me.

Comment: So in my example sentence, you would say that "what" is inappropriate? In that case, too, the items are not necessarily part of a clearly defined list; e.g., the instructions might be not to bring anything sharp or flammable.

Comment: No, I would not say "inappropriate"!  If I were an English teacher and your sentence came across my desk as part of an essay, I wouldn't mark it incorrect at all.  I am merely saying that "my way" is measurably more precise.  I am not the Imperial Arbiter of English Style and Usage.  LOL.  That would be William Strunk and E. B. White, but they never weighed in on this subject, so I have expressed my opinion, humble as it is.  Your preference is perfectly grammatical, never fear.

Comment: You see, "what items are permitted" would, if expanded, turn into a list.  Items are inherently listable.  "Which" implies granularity; "what" implies a general messy splat.  I hope I am not making myself unclear.

Comment: No, I understand what you mean. Thanks for your answer.